# How to fetch database table column names in java

Tags: java, database

I need to display all the columns from the table in java. So far I have tried resultSet java object but it is not working for me

```java
public class dbtest {

    public static Session session = null;

    public ArrayList < String > ColValue() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("Configuration\\Config.properties");

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(reader);

        String serverIp = p.getProperty("ServerIp");
        String keyspace = p.getProperty("ServerPwd");

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(serverIp).withCredentials("user", "password").build();
        session = cluster.connect(server);
        String query = null;
        String cqlStatement = "select * from table_name";

        ArrayList < String > casVal1 = new ArrayList < >();
        for (Row row: session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
            if (!casVal1.contains(query)) {
                casVal1.add(query);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(casVal1.size());
        System.out.println(casVal1);

        return (casVal1);
    }
}
```

Need all the columns in results as outcomes.

Comment: are you sure you have provided correct code as you mentioned in question ? I dont see usage of resultSet

Comment: Yes but it was not working

Comment: @Dhanraj what he is using is not JDBC, it is DataStax Cassandra Driver

Comment: Oh yes.. sorry .. I misundertood

Comment: If this is not [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), make that clear in the body and title of your Question. The Question and comments make this quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column via the `ResultSet.getColumnDefinitions` Method

```
com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet result = xxxxx;

for (Definition definition : result.getColumnDefinitions()) {
    String name = definition.getName();
}
```